# What's the pattern represented by the numbers in the two circles?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

The two circles in the following picture include two sets of numbers. I think that each set should represent a certain pattern. Now the question is what the pattern might be. To tell the truth, this is a question from an exercise book. I'm not asking people here to solve exercise questions for me. I've thought real hard and tried every possibility I could think of. Thank you very much indeed.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My idea: The set on the left is a sample of prime numbers, and the set on the right is a sample of composite numbers. Only one of the answer options is a composite number.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I think you're right. I only focused on the arithmetic relatioship between the numbers in the two sets and forgot to look from a whole view.